# How to put content into another file on specific div using php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to put content into another file in the specific `div`. I tried `file_put_contents` and `fopen`, these are working but i want to put content in different way. I have different email template, so i'm trying to add the message and subject dynamically into the template in the specific `div`, once content added then i will get content from template and send the email.

**What i'm trying**

In the `market_template.php` i have a template where i'm showing the `$_REQUEST` values in the relevant `div`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Marketing Template</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div id="subject">
        <?php   
            if(isset($_REQUEST['subject'])){ 
                echo $_REQUEST['subject'];
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="message">
        <?php 
            if(isset($_REQUEST['message'])){ 
                echo $_REQUEST['message'];
            }?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `core.php` i'm pushing the content through url query string and then i'm getting the `market_template.php` content.

```
// Getting content from file
$url = base_url.'market_template.php?eml_sub='.$subject.'&eml_msg='.$message;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(!empty($data)){
    echo $data; 
}
```

But the problem is that url query string does not adding full content into the template. For example i added in the URL
`?eml_sub=This is test subject`

But in the result i get only first word `This` the rest of content does not added and also second variable value is not adding.

So is there possible to put the value into another file and then get through php, i would like to appreciate. Thank you

Comment: It's because of the space, the space character in url is "%20"

Comment: The first comment is right. However, if this is a local file that you're trying to use in this way, a less awkward implementation for templating might be to use XSLT. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=XSLT&oq=XSLT

Comment: @VincentG Thanks for the guiding, so how to prevent these spaces because in the content there will be lot of spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment, in this part : `?eml_sub=This is test subject`, it will take only the first word `This` because of the space in the URL.

One way to prevent that behavior is to use `urlencode()` function and `urldecode()` function after treatment.

**Doc:**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php